# Analytics in iPhone game

Tags: iphone, xcode, analytics

I'm thinking about implementation of some simple analytics tool in my new game. 
I want to analyze for example, what scene is played at most,  etc. (I've 6 scenes in my game)
Is this possible, or it's against some Apple rules? 
And if it's possible, what's the best solution? What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and not against any of Apple's rules.  Google analytics has an SDK that is  easy to use and will track anything you want in your app.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/

I've used it many times before and it works great.

Comment: I'm only noob developer, but I'll try to implement google analytics. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Google Analytics SDK for iOS can be an option? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible, and it's definitely not against **Apple rules**. [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/) could be an option, but here is another:

So first, I would check which scene is actually visible by checking if each view controller's view is loaded

```
if (myViewController.isViewLoaded && myViewController.view.window) {

}
```

Then maybe start an NSTimer that triggers a method that adds one to a counter (separate ones for each view). Keep track of each counter, and whatever counter value corresponding to each view is the greatest, that view is being used the longest.